# Find free ip addresses in dhcpd.conf

Tags: linux, bash, grep, dhcp

I have a quite huge dhcpd.conf file on my CentOS gateway with ip addresses from a few networks. With grep I find out all strings, which contains ip's from needed network. How can I find all free ip's (my network is 192.168.77.0/24).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not bullet-proof but should work:

```
grep -oE '192\.168\.77\.[0-9]+' dhcpd.conf
```

Not bullet-proof as it will find also `192.168.77.999` which is not an IP.

---

Update:

If you are just searching for those which are free (you told that in comments) then use:

```
for ip in 192.168.77.{254..1} ; do
    grep -oE "$ip" dhcpd.conf > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
        echo "$ip is free"
    fi
done
```

Comment: It shows me ip's that I have in dhcpd.conf from this network

Comment: yes, but I need just a list of IP, that are free and my dhcpd.conf doesn't contain it

Comment: why do you need that?

Comment: I need that because I want to add some hosts in my dhcpd.conf file, but I don't know which static IP I should give to this host, because all IP in my dhcpd.conf are mixed.

Comment: It shows me all IP is free, i.e.: from 192.168.77.1 to 192.168.77.255 is free

Comment: actually, it shows me all IP that I have in ascending order, i.e. it that what I want but exactly the opposite :)

Comment: Sorry, but why do you have a brain? ;) Have updated this...

Comment: yes, I guessed already to replace "==" to "!=" and then see your update. Thank you very much, sorry for this, this is my first question here!

Comment: no I replaced `{1..254}` by `{254..1}` ...